# Is there any Dax query to calculate data for current date to previous specific month it may be 3 month from current date change slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

#### Scenario

I am working on one assignment to measure Doctors performance using Power BI.
I have two fact tables:

- `Patients Consulted`: [# Patients Consulted, Calendar FK, Doctor FK, Registration no.]
- `Procedures Completed`: [# Procedures Completed, Calendar FK, Doctor FK, registration no.]

and two dimensions:

- `Calendar`: [Calendar PK, Year, Month, Day]
- `Doctor`: [Doctor PK, Name, Surname]

#### Problem

When user selects `2020` and `March` in the slicers, I need to visualize the `# Procedures Completed` **in March** but `# Patients Consulted` **in the last X month**. If `X = -3`, it means I need to visualize the `# Patients Consulted` **in last month** that is march only

Since I am required how many patients procedure done in march who is consulted in -3,-4,-5,-6, I need 4 measures:

1. `# Patients Consulted -3 months`
2. `# Patients Consulted -4 months`
3. `# Patients Consulted -5 months`
4. `# Patients Consulted -6 months`

#### Expected Solution

How can I implement those 4 measures in my model?

Comment: Hi Shailendra thank you for your first question. To increase the chances the community help you, I would suggest to review the structure of the question (Scenario > Problem > Expected Solution). I would also highly suggest to present data for a simple but representative scenario, and the solution.

Comment: Ok thanks your valuable suggestions

Comment: Any supporting documents attachment options here

Comment: You may wish to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parallelperiod-function-dax